# Does getting all ten red jewels (teeth) on a world do anything?

Tags: rayman-jungle-run

In Rayman Jungle Run, getting five red jewels gives the creepy death guy enough teeth that he'll open up the land of the dead. (Why this would be escapes me.)

That land of the dead level serves as the tenth level for each world. is anything opened up by getting all ten gems on a world, or is it just the satisfaction of completion?

Comment: you mean rayman origins?  I think there was a final bossfight and another credit sequence

Comment: @ratchetfreak, no, but I did mean rayman *jungle* run.  I edited the question and tag to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acquiring all ten gems per world unlocks five achievements, one per world. As a necessary prerequisite, doing this will also unlock all of the wallpapers (since you need to collect Lums to unlock both wallpapers as well as gems).

Aside from those two things, there is no further reward for finding all fifty teeth; there doesn't even seem to be a meta-achievement for finding them all. In fact, when I did it, the game didn't treat finding the last tooth any differently from finding the tenth tooth in any other world.

Comment: Accepted! Seems inconsistent to make 5 gems an unlockable, but 10 just an achievement, though.